# OSError: [WinError 123] when I create kfp component

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, kfp

I'm trying to create a pipeline in Vertex AI with kfp using my own components from local notebook in Spyder.

When I run the following piece of code:

```py
@component(base_image="python:3.9", packages_to_install=["pandas"])
def create_dataset(
    gcs_csv_path_train: str,
    dataset: Output[Dataset],
):
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_csv(gcs_csv_path_train)
    dataset = df.pop('Class')
```

I get the following error:

```py
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '<ipython-input-11-b28c15ec667f>'
```

The error is not raised if I use a Jupyter notebook online.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: What is the value of **gcs_csv_path_train**? Does it follow the Windows file naming scheme?

Comment: @JohnHanley gsc_csv_path_train is the path to the file in the google cloud storage bucket and it is like that: gsc_csv_path_train = f"bucket/folder/file.csv". In the Traceback the error points to the line: def create_dataset(

Comment: Paths for Google Cloud storage look like this: **gs://bucket/folder/file.csv** The error message means that the filename is being intercepted as a file on a Windows filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the file path that you use in your code. Because there are some characters that are not accepted such as the colon “ : ” in Windows file names. You can see more [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file?redirectedfrom=MSDN) about Windows standar paths.

When using the path in the python code, please follow below:

- Use ‘r’ before any path- The r  is a string literal that lets treat
  any string as a raw string, which means all escape codes will be
  ignored.
- Use either double quotes “file-path” or single quote ‘file-path’ to
  specify the path.
- Don’t use a combination of both “” or ‘

Correct file path is as below

```
filepath = r'C:\Test\file\file-input-thecodebuzz.txt'
```

OR

```
filepath = r"C:\Test\file\file-input-thecodebuzz.txt"
```

You can see more [documentation](https://www.thecodebuzz.com/python-windows-error-123-filename-directory-name-syntax-is-incorrect/).